# Find the Matrix Representation of the Linear Transformation $ T : \mathcal{ P_{\mathit{N} }[\mathit{ R}] \to {\mathit{R^{N +1} }}}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\{ 1., x, \ldots  , x^N \}$ be the canonical basis of $\mathcal{ P_{\mathit{N} }[\mathit{ R}] } $ and let  $ T : \mathcal{ P_{\mathit{N} }[\mathit{ R}] \to {\mathit{R^{N +1} }}}$    such that

\begin{equation}
   T (p) =
   \begin{bmatrix}
     p(x_0)\\
     \vdots \\
     p(x_N)
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

in the canonical basis, How can I find the matrix representation of that linear transformation?

Comment: If you expand the definition of the matrix representation in this case, you'll discover that this is the $(N+1) \times (N+1)$ matrix whose columns are $T(1),T(x),T(x^2), \dots, T(x^N)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I like is as follows: to find the $j$th column of the matrix, compute the (coordinate vector of the) image of the $j$th basis element. In this case, the $j$-th basis element is $x^j$. The image of this element is
$$
T(x^{j-1}) = \pmatrix{x_0^{j-1} \\ \vdots \\ x_N^{j-1}}.
$$
So taking $j=3$, we see that the matrix of $T$ (relative to the canonical bases of $\mathcal P_N$ and $\Bbb R^{N + 1}$) has the form
$$
\pmatrix{?&?&x_0^2 &?&\cdots & ?\\
? & ?& x_1^2 & ? & \cdots & ?\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
? & ? & x_N^2 & ? & \cdots & ?}
$$